# bcrypt.compareSync(password,this.password); this method returns false

Tags: bcrypt

bcrypt compareSync this method always returns false. Even when the password matches with db field. Why it is returning false what is the mistake in my code??

```
        **//route for login backend

    router.post('/authenticate',function(req,res){
            User.findOne( { username:req.body.username } ).select('email username password').exec(function(err, user){
              if(err) throw err;
              if(!user){
                res.json({"success":false,"message":"authentication failed"});
              }
              else if(user){
                   var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);

            if(!validPassword){
                  res.json({"success":false,"message":"couldnot asuthenticate"});
                } else{
                  res.json({"success":true,"message":"authenticated"});
                }
              }
        })
          });


        //compare function

        UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password)
        {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        };**
```

Update:

1.my error was in pre save middleware that I have used

2.Cause of error

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;
bcrypt.hash(user.password, null,null, function(err, hash) {
if(err) return next(err);
user.password = hash;
 });
 next();
});
```

3.The next(); function is called outside my hash function.That is the reason why my compare results was always false.

4.It should have been:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;
bcrypt.hash(user.password, null,null, function(err, hash) {
if(err) return next(err);
user.password = hash;
 next();

});

});
```